# Кнопка "Удалить отмеченные" не удаляет записи

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Приветствую всех, прошу помочь доделать код, всё в принципе работает, только когда галочкой выбираешь в таблице строки для дальнейшего удаления, кнопка "удалить отмеченное" не работает, страница перезагружается, а записи остаются на месте.

```
<?php
    // соединение с базой данных
    require_once 'connect.php'; 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
<title>Админ-панель</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Таблица 2000 строк с фильтрацией</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='classes.css' type='text/css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='tabsort1.css' type='text/css'>
<script type='text/javascript'>var d0 = new Date()</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='tabtools1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='tabsort1.js'></script>
</head>

<?php
     // Отображаем результаты
echo '<p>Таблицы, имеющиеся в базе данных: </p>';
echo "<table class='sortable' id='t' border=1 >"; 

echo "<col class='id'><col class='name'><col class='width'><col class='profile'><col class='radius'><col class='price'><col class='prices'><col class='sellers'><col class='season'><col class='status'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th axis='num'>ID&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th>Улица&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th axis='num:alt'>Width&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th axis='num:alt'>Квартира&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th axis='num:alt'>Radius&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th axis='num'>Price&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th>Prices&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th axis='num'>Sellers&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th>Season&nbsp;</th>";
echo "<th axis='num:alt'>Status&nbsp;</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";

//Удаляем, если что
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    $result = mysql_query('DELETE FROM `user_profiles` WHERE `ID` = "'.$_GET['del'].'"');
    if ($result) {
        echo "<p>Товар удален.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }
}

//Получаем данные
echo '<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="GET">'; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user_profiles`") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" .$row['id']. "</td>";  
echo "<td axis='num' valign='top'>" .$row['mes']. "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" .$row['dom']. "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" .$row['kvar']. "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" .$row['password']. "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" .$row['phon']. "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" .$row['van1']. "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" .$row['van2']. "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'><a href=?del={$row['id']}>Delete</a></td> "; 
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="row[]" value="'.$row['id'].'" /></td>';  
echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
echo '<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Удалить отмеченные" />';

if ( isset ( $_GET['row'] ) )
{
    print_r($_GET) ;
  $ids = implode( ',', $_GET['row'] );
  $query = 'DELETE FROM items WHERE id IN ('.$ids.')';
  mysql_query( $query );
  header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
} 

?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что дает var_dump ($_GET['del']) ?

Comment: labris А где ты нашел такую строку?Я не вижу.

Comment: labris Или ты имел ввиду, что я в этом месте не правильно прописал код? Вообще по одной запись удаляется без проблем, в том месте, о котором ты говоришь, а так при проверке и нажатия кнопки "Удалить отмеченные" он мне выдает такие комментарии - `Array ( [submitForm] => Удалить отмеченные )` , но что я не так делаю, не пойму совсем...

Comment: Я имел в виду, что для того, чтобы проверить, что выдает переменная $_GET['del'] , надо вывести ее через var_dump ($_GET['del']) . То есть поставить эту строку перед if (isset($_GET['del']))  и посмотреть, что приходит.

Comment: у вас там еще внизу должно писаться `headers already sent`. 1) Не делайте удаление через GET, этот тип запроса существует для получения данных, для изменения/удаления есть POST и прочие менее используемые. 2) Нельзя отправит header после того, как что уже выведено, ваш header-location в конце не будет работать. 3) не используйте расширение mysql оно устарело 4) используйте шаблонизаторы, разделяйте логику и представление

Comment: labris я так сделал, он выдал `NULL`

Comment: teran 1)GET я прописал, чтобы в адресной строке посмотреть. 2)Я эту часть взял с готового кода, если честно, сам не знаю что она делает и зачем. 3)Как вариант решил такой, других не нашел. 4)Извините, никогда о таком не слышал, если есть знание где найти, был бы благодарен. Задача у меня такая, через форму принимаю данные, после необходимо проверить эти данные в виде таблицы и при обнаружении двойника его удалить. Поэтому и хотел удалять сразу несколько записей, т.к. их у меня накапливается более 700.